# New features for Website Custom Audiences‏

Tags: wordpress, facebook

Is it possible to connect this on WordPress site ? Its new feature and I want to know is it possible and would it make sense?

**Introducing new features for Website Custom Audiences‏**

https://www.facebook.com/business/news/Multi-Product-Ads-and-Enhanced-Custom-Audiences-from-your-Website

Maybe anybody knows about that, and can help me a little bit.

Comment: I think it's probably up to you as to whether it makes sense. What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using WCA for most of my websites. It's good to keep your website visitors data so that you can run remarketing campaign targeting them easily in near future.

This video will show you how to install WCA script on WordPress site:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pJFTeIPs3-Q

If you're not using WordPress, that's fine. Just paste the tracking pixel script inside your HTML file before `</head>` tag close.